# How can i show neuorph example in my android?

Tags: android, netbeans

what i am trying to do its simple. but it did not work for me . 
i am fowling this link :

http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/tutorials/android_image_recognition_using_neuroph.htm

i just need to try this tutorial in the link .

1-I download Netbeans 8.1 
2-I  download android visual studio . 
3. I make new VDA with the same API for both of them . 
4. I give the location for android sdk in the netbeans . 
5. in the link giving above its say i should have a nerouph example that is not showing in my emulator ,

Please if any one familiar with this , please help me thanks

Comment: That tutorial was made when Android 2.1 was the latest release. Consider working from Android Studio from now on. You can still use neuroph without having to download it via gradle:
`compile 'org.beykery:neuroph:2.92'`

Comment: Thanks , but i did not rely understand , can you provide steps please

Comment: How i can get this neuroph in my android application ?